# Force the owner and group for the contents of a tar file?

Tags: permissions, users, tar

I would like to create a tar file with contents belonging to an owner:group pair who do not exist on the system from which the file is being made.

Here's the direction I've tried:

```
tar ca --owner='otherowner' --group='othergroup' mydata.tgz mydata
```

And when running this command, I get the following error:

```
tar: otherowner: Invalid owner
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Is there a way to force tar to accept the owner:group, even though neither of them exist on the system from which the file is being created?

Comment: Note that --owner is not an option supported by tar. This is a non-portable GNUism. With star, you e.g. use the built-in find and specify -chown username/userid -chgrp groupname/groupid.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Linux doesn't use internally owners and groups names but numbers - UIDs and GIDs. Users and groups names are mapped from contents of /etc/passwd and /etc/group files for convenience of user. Since you don't have 'otherowner' entry in any of those files, Linux doesn't actually know which UID and GID should be assigned to a file. Let's try to pass a number instead:

```
$ tar cf archive.tar test.c --owner=0 --group=0
$ tar -tvf archive.tar 
-rw-rw-r-- root/root        45 2013-01-10 15:06 test.c
$ tar cf archive.tar test.c --owner=543543 --group=543543
$ tar -tvf archive.tar 
-rw-rw-r-- 543543/543543    45 2013-01-10 15:06 test.c
```

It seems to work.

Comment: Interesting! So the tar command must be polling the system for the user and group numbers to match the names I was trying to use. Thanks!

Comment: A note for others coming across this: tar automatically outputs user/group _names_ when using the `-tvf` flags. To view the current _numbers_ for files in an archive use a command like this: `$ tar --numeric-owner -tvf archive.tar`

Comment: Actually with my tar version I can enter any username I'd like and have it stored in the tar file (but with my numeric user id by default). While listing you get the usernames by default but the user ids using the `--numeric-owner` flag. What's more interesting is that you can set both using `--owner=name:1234` or `--group=groupname:4711`. Source: [function parse_owner_group of the tar source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/tar.c?h=release_1_29#n1208)

Comment: It is probably worth noting that the ustar (standard on BSD and Linux) tar header encodes both numeric UID/GID values as well as the user and group names. When unpacking, the names are used first, if they're present in the header and match users and groups defined on the system. The numeric UID and GID will only be used as a fallback.

Answer (score 2):

Add the params `--no-same-owner --no-same-permissions` with `tar`. Take a [look at the docs](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-tar/).

Comment: Those options are only used when extracting files from a tar archive -- not creating one.

Comment: You are right @AnthonyGeoghegan!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a piece of code to replace the user/group with ids on the fly:

```
tar ca --owner="$(id -u ***otherowner***)" --group="$(id -g ***othergroup***)" mydata.tgz mydata
```

Comment: No. If **id** knows how to resolve the name, **tar** knows too. The question is about a user name unknown to the system.